# Pick values form an array of objects and create a new one : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array of objects of the format:

```
input = [ 
  { key : "Test1", value: 25, total: 100},
  { key : "Test2", value: 35, total: 200},
  { key : "Test3", value: 45, total: 300},
  { key : "Test4", value: 55, total: 400},
  { key : "Test5", value: 65, total: 500}
]
```

I basically have to fetch some properties out of this and form a new array that should look something like this. `text` is equivalent to its text representation that is maintained in a separate object.

```
textObj = { "Test1" : "Test1Eq" , "Test2" : "Test2Eq" , "Test3" : "Test3Eq" , "Test4" : "Test4Eq" , "Test5" : "Test6Eq" }
```

I just have to fetch count of `Text1,  Text4, Text 5` and return its text equivalent and its count in a new array.

Result

```
output = [ 
  { text : "Test1Eq", count: 25},
  { text : "Test4Eq", count: 55},
  { text : "Test5Eq", count: 65}
]
```

Method I tried

```
const res = input.map(item=>{
      return{
        text :textObj[item.key],
        count: item.count
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the count, you can use `array#find`.

```js
const input = [ { key : "Test1", value: 25, total: 100}, { key : "Test2", value: 35, total: 200}, { key : "Test3", value: 45, total: 300}, { key : "Test4", value: 55, total: 400}, { key : "Test5", value: 65, total: 500} ],
      textObj = { "Test1" : "Test1Eq" , "Test2" : "Test2Eq" , "Test3" : "Test3Eq" , "Test4" : "Test4Eq" , "Test5" : "Test6Eq" },
      keys = ['Test1', 'Test4', 'Test5'],
      result = keys.map(key => ({
        text: textObj[key],
        count: input.find(o => o.key === key)?.value
      }));
console.log(result);
```